# Get the value in ( ) from a text file and write it to a text file using python

Tags: python

Read a text file containing

> segment:xy (10472.14 3793.00) xy (10471.87 3796.71) width (0.00)

and get the values present in the xy(  ) and write them to a new text file on disk

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Read the Python online documentation: to start with look for `open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not give much information, but this very rudimentary code will do the job (untested code):

```
whole = open('my_file','r').read()
for x in whole.split('\n'):
    buf = x[10:28] + x[34:49] # adjust these values accordingly

open('out_file','w').write(buf)
```

Mind that this code will not "adapt" to different types of strings (e.g. mode decimal points) and for this reason a regular expression solution could be a better method but that would be your homework ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You really should try to write *something* yourself:

Open the input file and read the `line`.

Open an output file for write.

`finditer` from the `re` module executes successive searches, and returns a *match object* on success.  Call this in a loop.  Construct a regular expression that looks for 'xy (', then anything, then ')'.  The inner parentheses capture the "anything".  You will need a minimal match.

Write out the first element of the tuple retuned by the `groups()` method called on the match object (`m`).  This will be the captured "anything".

Now go and read the manual.